# Screen Scraping Twitter Page with Unicode Equal Comparison Failure Python

Tags: python, twitter, screen-scraping, screen

I'm using the following code  to obtain a list of a user's followers on twitter:

```
import urllib
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

#code only looks at one page of followers instead of continuing to all of a user's followers
#decided to only use a small sample 

site = "http://mobile.twitter.com/NYTimesKrugman/following"
friends = set()
response = urllib.urlopen(site)
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
names = soup.findAll('a', {'href': True})
for name in names:
    a = name.renderContents()
    b = a.lower()
    if ("http://mobile.twitter.com/" + b) == name['href']:
        c = str (b)
        friends.add(c)

for friend in friends:
    print friend
print ("Done!")
```

However, I get the following results:

```
NYTimeskrugman
nytimesphoto
rasermus

Warning (from warnings module):
   File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Columbia Job\Python Crawler\Twitter     Crawler\crawlerversion14.py", line 42
    if ("http://mobile.twitter.com/" + b) == name['href']:
 UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
amnesty_norge
zynne_
fredssenteret
oljestudentene
solistkoret
```

....(and so it continues)

It would appear that I was able to get most of the names of the following but I received a somewhat random error. It didn't stop the code from finishing however...I was hoping that someone could enlighten me as to what happened?

Comment: The warning comes because you're trying to compare a (non-ascii) bytestring with a unicode string, and it doesn't know how to decode the bytestring into ascii. But really, you should just use a library to interrogate twitter anyway. See https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries#python

Comment: `u"http://mobile.twitter.com/"`

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if my answer will be useful several years later, but I rewrote your code using requests instead of urllib.

I think it's better to made **an other selection with the class "username"** to consider only followers names !

Here's the stuff :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

site = "http://mobile.twitter.com/paulkrugman/followers"
friends = set()
response = requests.get(site)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
names = soup.findAll('a', {'href': True})
for name in names:
    pseudo = name.find("span", {"class": "username"})
    if pseudo:
        pseudo = pseudo.get_text()
        friends.add(pseudo)

for friend in friends:
    print (friend)
print("Done !")
```

@paulkrugman appears in every set, so don't forget to delete it !